# Converting bgra stream to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying to record video of iOS simulator using the following command;

`./fbsimctl stream --bgra --fps 12 - | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -s 414x736 -framerate 12  -i - -f h264 -r 12 - | ffplay -`

The problem is the resulting video is garbled.

It seems like ffmpeg is not converting bgra format properly.

Are there any other parameters that I need to pass?

There is a warning in the middle of the sample output pasted below:

`Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[swscaler @ 0x7f8342009000] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss`

Here is the sample output;

```
./fbsimctl stream --bgra --fps 12 - | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -s 414x736 -framerate 12  -i - -f h264 -r 12 - | ffplay -
ffmpeg version 4.0.2ffplay version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers Copyright (c) 2003-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)

  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Running /usr/bin/xcode-select --print-path with environment {
    HOME = "/Users/sumancherukuri";
    PATH = "/Users/sumancherukuri/Projects/webrtc/webrtc_ios/depot_tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin";
}
Connection Did Connect => Bridge: Framebuffer ((null)) | HID (null) | (null)
079C6C51-C335-4273-A566-7D0667693F99 | iPhone X | Booted | iPhone X | iOS 11.4 | x86_64: launch: Bridge: Framebuffer ((null)) | HID (null) | (null)

Mounting Surface with Attributes: {
    format = BGRA;
    "frame_size" = 11069184;
    height = 2436;
    "row_size" = 4544;
    width = 1125;
}
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 117006 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGRA / 0x41524742), bgra, 414x736, 117006 kb/s, 12 tbr, 12 tbn, 12 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
[swscaler @ 0x7f8342009000] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss
[libx264 @ 0x7f8343801800] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f8343801800] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 2.2, 4:4:4 8-bit
Output #0, h264, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv444p, 414x736, q=-1--1, 12 fps, 12 tbn, 12 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1

listen started: Streaming Video
frame=   56 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   frame=   79 fps= 77 q=26.0 size=     950kB time=00:00:01.75 bitrate=4448.9kbits/frame=  116 fps= 76 q=26.0 size=    2501kB time=00:00:04.83 bitrate=4239.1kbits/Input #0, h264, from 'pipe:':q=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
```

Thanks,

--Suman

Comment: Does `./fbsimctl stream --bgra --fps 12 - | ffplay -f rawvideo -video_size 414x736 -framerate 12 -pixel_format bgra -` play fine?

Comment: No, it plays a garbled black and white noise on the screen. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is the resulting video is garbled.

I encountered exactly the same problem today.
The cause is, fbsimctl bgra output is in BMP file style and each image array is padded by 0 so that its length becomes a multiple of 4 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format for the detail).

By extending the specified image size to a multiple of 4, I resolved this problem.
For your case, you should change `-s 414x736` to `-s 416x736`.

Answer (score 0):

*Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speed loss*

It means one of the input or output dimensions, when scaling, is not an integer multiple of 16.

The ffmpeg accelerated scaling code (e.g. MMX or SSE) will not behave in an optimal manner when encoding, i.e. may be slow. This is nothing to worry about, nor anything you need to do something about.

There is of course absolutely nothing you can do about this if it's the input file which has video dimensions that are not an exact multiple of 16. Only the output dimensions are controllable by the user.

Another answer posted here suggests altering one dimension by 4, but the point is that the ffmpeg code requires the dimensions to be exact multiples not of four but of sixteen.